# Render a dynamically created button inside a dynamically created iframe and pass messages from the iFrame to parent

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

So I have a button that's created dynamically and I want to render it inside another dynamically created iFrame. I'm trying the below code but that just renders the button in the following way:

[image]

```
const widgetButton =  document.createElement('button');
var iframe = document.createElement('iframe');

widgetButton.onclick = openWidget;
widgetButton.innerHTML = 'Hello';
iframe.src = 'data:text/html;charset=utf-8,' + encodeURI(widgetButton);
```

Maybe I need to change the type in 'data:' in the *src*. But I'm not sure what that would be.

EDIT:

I tried the following as well. But this time `openWidget` remains undefined as expected. So is there as way I can inject this function (may be injecting `<script>` inside this iFrame?

```
        var html = `<button onclick="openWidget()">HEllo</button>`;
        
        iframe.src = 'data:text/html;charset=utf-8,' + encodeURI(html);

        document.body.appendChild(iframe);
```

Comment: `widgetButton.outerHTML`? since the data type is `text/html`?

Comment: I can't answer your particular question, but the reason why the widgetButton doesn't get in is because widgetButton is an object and when an object.toString() is called it'll be [object Name] for classs\es.

Comment: You don't ..  An iFrame, by definition is meant to place OUTSIDE content within your page.  As such it is designed to not accept  inputs or edits from the "surrounding page" once rendered.  Imagine if you loaded a bank's URL into your iFrame -- and could insert a button that would collect login information onClick.

Comment: @Zak I see. So I tried another way. Please see my edits. Now is there a way I could inject a script inside this iframe that onClick of this button could invoke my method?

Comment: No .. Because the button falls in the scope of that iFrame .. You cannot "cross pollinate" from surrounding page to iFrame here.  The only way to run JS FROM the frame is to insert it INTO the iFrame .. IE `var html = '<button onclick="alert('hey')">Hello</button>';`  JS calls cannot be made across that "boundary"

Comment: @Zak Yeah I just saw this for myself when I did this.
 `var html = <script>function clickWidget() {alert('hello')}</script><button onclick="clickWidget()">Hello</button>`;
alert works. But as you say, I can't inject the original onclick method that's outside of this iframe.

Comment: I think this might work: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage
I'm trying to find a solution through it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
const html = `<script>
      function buttonClicked(){
      window.parent.postMessage("widgetButtonClicked", '*');
    }
</script>
<body>
       <button onclick="buttonClicked()">Widget</button>
</body>`;


const iframe = document.createElement('iframe');

iframe.src = 'data:text/html;charset=utf-8,' + encodeURI(html);

document.body.appendChild(iframe);
```

And then inside parent,

```
window.addEventListener("message", (event)=>{
   if(event.data === 'widgetButtonClicked'){
     openWidget()
   }
})
```